# How do you swap element position in a collection in backbone.js

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js.  The elements in my collection are just in the order that they are added.  However, I want the ability to switch the position of elements.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    swapItems : function(index1, index2) {
        this.models[index1] = this.models.splice(index2, 1, this.models[index1])[0];
    }
});
```

This accesses the models array directly then will swap the items specified by the indices.